# Search posts with meta data in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search

I have created a site for study in abroad and i want to create search form for courses in site. I have added meta box for posting, but i cannot solve search form for meta data in posts.

Search form must be:

1) Countries

2) Course Languaes

3) Course Types

4) City of School

This is code in `functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'thim_add_course_meta' ) ) {
    function thim_add_course_meta( $meta_box ) {
        $fields             = $meta_box['fields'];
        $fields[]           = array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Yaş Həddi', 'eduma' ),
            'id'   => 'thim_course_age',
            'type' => 'text',
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'yas heddi', 'eduma' ),
            'std'  => esc_html__( '18', 'eduma' )
        );

        $fields[]           = array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Dil', 'eduma' ),
            'id'   => 'thim_course_language',
            'type' => 'text',
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'Language\'s used for studying', 'eduma' ),
            'std'  => esc_html__( 'English', 'eduma' )
        );
        $fields[]           = array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Şəhər', 'eduma' ),
            'id'   => 'thim_course_city',
            'type' => 'text',
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'Language\'s used for studying', 'eduma' ),
            'std'  => esc_html__( 'Şəhər', 'eduma' )
        );
        $fields[]           = array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Ölkə', 'eduma' ),
            'id'   => 'thim_course_country',
            'type' => 'text',
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'Language\'s used for studying', 'eduma' ),
            'std'  => esc_html__( 'Ölkə', 'eduma' )
        );

        $meta_box['fields'] = $fields;

        return $meta_box;
    }

}
```

And how to i can change meta box type (from text to array)?